# Azure Logic App stops execution when getting 401 from an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

When calling an Azure Function from a Logic App if the status code returned from the Azure Function is 401 the Logic App stops executing.

This is a new Logic App testing for something for work. I have a conditional after the Azure Function call checking if the status code is 200 or not but it never gets to that conditional if the status code returned is 401.

[image: Azure Logic App]

I would have expected that the Logic App continued to execute and the conditional should have been hit checking the status code.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this! In the conditional under the Azure Function you need to "Configure Run After" and select "has failed" as well as "is successful".

[image: Configure Run After]